# Python/XML number of child nodes

Tags: python, xml, xhtml

what I want to get from below xml file is:
if number of `<broader>` nodes inside `<term>` node > 1 
AND
any of these `<broader>` node's value is equal to `<id>` node's value 
THEN
print `<value>` node text.

```
            <results>
            <term>
                <altLabel>
                    <value>Label1</value>
                </altLabel>
                <broader>11</broader>
                <id>1</id>
            </term>
            <term>
                <altLabel>
                    <value>Label2</value>
                </altLabel>
                <broader>22</broader>
                <broader>2</broader>
                <id>2</id>
            </term>
            <term>
                <altLabel>
                    <value>Label3</value>
                </altLabel>
                <broader>3</broader>
                <broader>33</broader>
                <id>3</id>
            </term>
            <term>
                <altLabel>
                    <value>Label4</value>
                </altLabel>
                <broader>44</broader>
                <broader>44</broader>
                <id>4</id>
            </term>
        </results>
```

So that for above XML I suppose to get:

```
Label2
Label3
```

NOTE: number of child nodes inside `<term>` node may vary. This is just a sample xml, so that I'm not interested in pointing on any specific element of table.

Comment: Why isn't `Label4` part of your expected results?

Comment: because non of Label4 'broader' node = Label4' id' node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using builtin [xml](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) module, the sytax is quite similar to beautifulsoup :)

Replace `path_to_xml` to your xml file path

```
from xml.etree import cElementTree as ET
xml_dat = ET.parse(path_to_xml).getroot()
for term in xml_dat.iter('term'):
    broaders = term.findall('broader')
    if len(broaders) > 1:
        for broader in broaders:
            if term.find('id').text == broader.text:
                print(term.find('altLabel').find('value').text)
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do, using `BeautifulSoup` is to loop over all `term` tags, and check if their id text is equal to any of their `broader` texts:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(doc, 'lxml') #  doc is your string
termList = soup.findAll("term")
for term in termList:
    if len(term.findAll("broader")) > 1:
        for broader in term.findAll("broader"):
            if term.id.text == broader.text:
                print(term.value.text)
```

Will print:

```
Label2
Label3
```

Comment: Not enough. Please mind the condition that number of 'broader nodes needs to be > 1.

Comment: Oh, there's a possibility there's no `broader` tag inside one of `term`s? I wasn't aware because I was focused on the example, sorry. I'll edit it asap.

Comment: @misio_jasio I think it's good to go, now! thanks for the comment! :D

Comment: Yes, there is a possibility that there will be no  'broader' nodes inside 'term' node.